# CANNOT_EXCLUDE_DOCUMENT: This document cannot be excluded for this recipient

Tags: docusignapi

I am seeing a weird behavior with this test eSign transaction:

```
{
    "compositeTemplates": [
        {
            "inlineTemplates": [
                {
                    "documents": [
                        {
                            "documentBase64": "BASE64STRING",
                            "documentId": "7",
                            "fileExtension": "PDF",
                            "name": "DOCUMENT7"
                        }, {
                            "documentBase64": "BASE64STRING",
                            "documentId": "10",
                            "fileExtension": "PDF",
                            "name": "DOCUMENT10"
                        }, {
                            "documentBase64": "BASE64STRING",
                            "documentId": "12",
                            "fileExtension": "PDF",
                            "name": "DOCUMENT12"
                        }, {
                            "documentBase64": "BASE64STRING",
                            "documentId": "17",
                            "fileExtension": "PDF",
                            "name": "DOCUMENT17"
                        }, {
                            "documentBase64": "BASE64STRING",
                            "documentId": "18",
                            "fileExtension": "PDF",
                            "name": "DOCUMENT18"
                        }, {
                            "documentBase64": "BASE64STRING",
                            "documentId": "19",
                            "fileExtension": "PDF",
                            "name": "DOCUMENT19"
                        }, {
                            "documentBase64": "BASE64STRING",
                            "documentId": "20",
                            "fileExtension": "PDF",
                            "name": "DOCUMENT20"
                        }
                    ],
                    "recipients": {
                        "signers": [
                            {
                                "email": "SIGNER1@mailinator.com",
                                "excludedDocuments": [
                                    "20"
                                ],
                                "name": "SIGNER1",
                                "recipientId": "2",
                                "tabs": {
                                    "signHereTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "documentId": "7",
                                            "pageNumber": "1",
                                            "recipientId": "2",
                                            "xPosition": "45",
                                            "yPosition": "628"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }, {
                                "email": "SIGNER2@mailinator.com",
                                "excludedDocuments": [
                                "7"
                            ],
                                "name": "SIGNER2",
                                "recipientId": "3",
                                "tabs": {
                                    "signHereTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "documentId": "20",
                                            "pageNumber": "1",
                                            "recipientId": "3",
                                            "xPosition": "45",
                                            "yPosition": "628"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "sequence": "1"
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "serverTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": "1",
                    "templateId": "f7e03095-8fd0-4c0a-9ec4-50d8fcee9b17"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "emailSubject": "Test eSign",
    "enforceSignerVisibility": "True",
    "status": "sent"
}
```

When I send it to the DocuSign v2.1 api `{{baseUrl}}/v2.1/accounts/{{accountId}}/envelopes`
I receive the following error:

```
{
    "errorCode": "CANNOT_EXCLUDE_DOCUMENT",
    "message": "This document cannot be excluded for this recipient. Recipient: SIGNER2 cannot be excluded from Document:DOCUMENT20"
}
```

However, as you can see in the recipient "SIGNER2", the list of excluded documents doesn't contain the document 20 but this one :

```
"excludedDocuments": [
    "7"
```

],

If I remove the document "7" from the list of excludedDocuments, then the transaction will go through.
I have tested with any templates and it fails just the same.
If I don't use the [CompositeTemplate](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/templates/composite/) structure, it succeeds.

Anything I am missing or not seeing ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you also have a serverTemplate. Is it possible that one has tabs for the document in question for SIGNER2? remember it all becomes one big envelope

Comment: That's what I thought at first but it's not the case Here is my template,as I mentioned above it fails with ANY templates:
Can you reproduce the issue on your end ?
"recipients": {
  "signers": [
   {
    "tabs": {
 "initialHereTabs": [
      {
     "name": "InitialHere",
    "documentId": "1",
     "recipientId": "77714337",
       "pageNumber": "1",
       "xPosition": "213",
       "yPosition": "292",
       "tabType": "initialhere"
      }
     ]
    "recipientId": "77714337",
    "routingOrder": "1",
    "roleName": "Cosigner2",
    "recipientType": "signer"
   }
  ]

Comment: I'm confused, the issue is document 7 or document 20? why don't you start with a simple case and work back up. I think there's an issue here, but I can't really build the same thing, I can build a simple with 2 documents and exclude 1.

Comment: I already have other cases that work but I'm trying to figure out why this specific one doesn't work and if it's a DocuSign bug. DocuSign error says the issue is document 20 even though my request does not exclude document 20 but if I happen to remove document 7 it works. This is only my observation, I don't know if the issue is actually with 7 or 20.

Comment: so you have a set of 6 documents you want to exclude. can you try 1 by 1 to exclude one at a time and see which one causes the error?

Comment: It appears to me that document 7 is what you said is causing the issue. So excluding the other 5 works just fine? exactly as you expect?

Comment: I can try to exclude 1 by 1 but can someone tell me that they reproduce the issue first ? Additionally, can someone from DocuSign tell me why the DocuSign error states that the document 20 cannot be excluded when it's not excluded in the first place ? That doesn't seem to make sense, does it ? is that a bug?

Comment: @InbarGazit, after more testing I found that if I only exclude the document "7" the error appears. However, DocuSign references the document 20. Is that normal ? Am I missing something ? Signer2 doesn't have any tabs in the document 7, why can't it be excluded ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more than 4 months since I have created a DocuSign case, it was finally reviewed and considered a bug on the DocuSign API.
This bug has been announced as something that will be fixed in the future.

> This issue is currently open and in the hands of our engineering team
> that have come with a workaround. This issue is due to the
> compositeTemplate call re-generated document Ids, so instead of
> honoring the values provided for document id the documents are
> renumbered, in the created envelope DOCUMENT20 does have an ID of 7,
> so that's where the error is coming from. To remove DOCUMENT20 you
> would have to send exclude document 7 in your call body.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Settings > Sending Settings > Document Visibility
And change Document Visibility to "Must sign to view, unless sender"
If this does not work, open a case and make sure to include the API request logs.